# How do I set up alpine to read local Unix generated mail

Tags: maildir, alpine-mail

Linux delivers mail to home directory: `/home/linker/Maildir` under which are 3 directories `new`, `cur`, `tmp`.

When I type `mail` I get `mail: /home/linker/Maildir/: Is a directory`, which is not useful.

I have installed alpine but can't get it access the Maildir directory (above) to read the mails in `new`.

I guess its all about the `.pinerc`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `alpine` program does not support Maildir format mailboxes out of the box, although there is a [patch](http://alpine.x10host.com/alpine/info/maildir.html) floating around out there somewhere that adds this feature.

If you're using Maildir, you can use `mutt`, which works great with maildir folders, or you can set an IMAP server (e.g., [dovecot](http://www.dovecot.org/)) that supports Maildir, and then configure `alpine` and other mail clients to use IMAP for accessing your mail.

Comment: @user1082991 Welcome to Stack Exchange. If this answer solved your problem, please [mark the answer as accepted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) by clicking on the check mark. This is our way of thanking the answerer here (assuming your problem was indeed solved).

Comment: The patch link is broken.

Comment: Well, the answer is almost ten years old, and even when it was originally written the patch was unmaintained :). I've updated the answer with a new link.